# Increment dataframe column from a certain value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I have a dataframe and I want to create a new column based on a condition on a different column. Create the new column "ans" that starts with 2348 and increment based on the column "ix". In the "ix" column if the value is the same as the next one keep the "ans" column the same and if its different increment "ans"

Thank you for your answer

```
  index   ix  
    1     pa 
    2     pa
    3     pa
    4     pe
    5     fc
    6     pb
    7     pb
    8     df
```

should result in:-

```
  index   ix  ans
    1     pa   2348
    2     pa   2348
    3     pa   2348
    4     pe   2349
    5     fc   2350
    6     pb   2351
    7     pb   2351
    8     df   2352
```

Comment: What should happen for the last value since there is nothing to compare to? It seems in your example you're incrementing based on the previous value being different? Just want to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check equality of ix column with it's previous row using `shift()`, and use `cumsum()`:

```
df['ans'] = (
    df['ix'].ne(df['ix'].shift(1))
    ).cumsum().add(2348) - 1
```

prints:

```
   index  ix   ans
0      1  pa  2348
1      2  pa  2348
2      3  pa  2348
3      4  pe  2349
4      5  fc  2350
5      6  pb  2351
6      7  pb  2351
7      8  df  2352
```